# Python regular expression replace string

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code:

```
 a="32<2>fdssa</2>ffdsa32"
 re.sub(r'<(\d+)>|</(\d+)>',"item",a)
```

The result I get:

```
32itemfdssaitemffdsa32
```

I want the result:

```
32<item>fdssa</item>ffdsa32
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to capture `</` part.

```
re.sub(r'(</?)\d+>',r"\1item>",a)
```

Since I made `/` as optional, `(</?)` will capture `<` or `</`

**Example:**

```
>>> a="32<2>fdssa</2>ffdsa32"
>>> re.sub(r'(</?)\d+>',r"\1item>",a)
'32<item>fdssa</item>ffdsa32'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> re.sub(r'(</?)\d+(?=>)', r'\1item', a)
'32<item>fdssa</item>ffdsa32'
```

- `(</?)` matches `<` or `</` captures to `\1`
- `\d+` matches one or more digits.
- `(?=>)` positive look ahead, checks if the digits is followed by `>`, but doesn't consume them